# Use different highlight colors for favorite tags in the main page

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, highlighting, tag-highlighting

I have three favorite tags in the main page.

Currently they are all highlighted with the same color.

I would like to see each one with a different color so I can tell which one is which without having to read each tag in the question.

This way I can differentiate my favorite tags of which  "I can give an answer" ( Java in my case )  from those favorite tags from which I don't know anything at all and I like to learn about ( let's say Earlang )

It had happened to me that I click on a question, read it, and suddenly I feel like in the "Twilight Zone" only to realize after a few seconds, I clicked on a "favorite to learn" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be difficult if:

- **you have multiple favorites on the same question.**
  This could be solved if you assign priority to the tag order as listed in the question.  The danger here is the triggering edit wars between users wanting their colors 'just right'
- **you have a large list of favorites.** This could be solved by assigning a color to a tag when you enter it as a favorite, and allowing for duplicates - potentially using a preset palatte.

Comment: Just mix the colors :D

Comment: @Spencer Ruport - Stripes would be better. No wait, **alternate flashing colors**. Brilliant!

Comment: I was about to say: "We are grown ups here, we wouldn't fight for the colors" .. but in a second thought I've seen fight just because someone said: "Hi".

Comment: I'm thinking of it as a customization in the preferences page, more than an automatic assignation .

Comment: Why do you say this is difficult and then explain how it actually isn't difficult?

Answer (score 1):

I could see something that being useful. Custom colors on tags where you could edit the tag and give it a certain RGB value. Either that or you would have to have potentially a preset number of colors to work from, which may end up repeating for users with lots of highlighted tags.

Comment: I'm thinking more in the first option. In the preferences select the color for each tag

Comment: Plus, you could carefully specify the RGB values necessary to evoke **rainbows**.  Ponies would be sure to follow in short order.

Comment: Don't fear someone's personal ponies. You don't have to witness them. :)

Answer (score 1):

I could see this being an intersting feature, but not really necessary. If I want to distinguish and see the questions for just one of my interesting tags, I just click that tag.